# intel-graphics-update-tool failed to install Intel Graphics Driver

Tags: dependencies

When I'm using `intel-graphics-update-tool` to install Intel Graphics Driver, I get this error.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this today as well, exact same thing. The answer is that the installer works on Ubuntu 16.04 release but does not anymore after all the updates to kernel & mesa. Consider this 16.04.1 if you want.  For me the problem happens on Ubuntu Mint 18.2 after the lsb_release trick. The Intel tool simply has not been updated to deal with it. But perhaps newer (non-LTS) releases?

Source: all later releases of intel tool: eg https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.6

"All support for Ubuntu* 16.04 ended when the Graphics Installer v2.0.2 was release (14 Nov 2016)."

Comment: 404
OOPS, WE COULDN'T FIND THAT PAGE
Please try our search tool or going back to our home page

Comment: Do you mean the 01.org site? The page still loads normally today when clicking on the supplied link.